# Error: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency. Does anyone have a solution?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a music player as part of a project I'm working on but I have this error. Does anyone have a solution?

[eslint]
src\components\MusicPlayer.jsx
Line 48:9:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'togglePlay'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I've made the code shorter for this example. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'


function MusicPlayer({songs}) {

      //Test 
const songFiles = songs.map(song => song.songFile)

    //Hooks
    const audioPlayer = useRef()

    //State
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const { songClicked} = useContext(songContext)
    // setSongClicked
    const [currentSong, setCurrentSong] = useState(songClicked);
    const [isPlaying, setisPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [volume, setVolume] = useState(30);
    const [mute, setMute] = useState(false);


     useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentSong(songClicked)
        
         if (songClicked) {
             audioPlayer.current.play()
         }
        
         if (songClicked) {
             togglePlay()
         }

     }, [songClicked])
 

    useEffect(() => {
        if(audioPlayer) {
            audioPlayer.current.volume = volume / 100;
        }
    }, [volume]);


    function togglePlay() {
        if(!isPlaying) {
            audioPlayer.current.play()
        } else {
            audioPlayer.current.pause()
        }
        setisPlaying(isPlaying => !isPlaying)
    }
```

Comment: You can just add `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` to disable that lint.

Comment: where do I add it? What line?

Comment: Just above the dependency array.

Comment: @BikasLin Please avoid suggesting other people to disable eslint. It's mostly right with it's warnings and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> useEffect has a missing dependency. Does anyone have a solution?

I guess this error says it all. Simply include `togglePlay` in the *dependency* array of the `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (currentSong !== songClicked) {
     setCurrentSong(songClicked)
   }
    
}, [songClicked, togglePlay]);
           //    ^^^^^^^^^
```

Also make sure to wrap your `togglePlay` with `useCallback` keep the function reference between renders. Else, you could end up with an *infinite* loop.

```
const togglePlay = useCallback(() => {
   ...
}, []);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! It starts an infinite loop even though I wrapped the function in useCallback

Comment: My play and pause buttons are flickering really fast. I think its changing the state from playing !playing

Comment: This is the error I keep getting whenever I try to fix it. Any idea??

Comment: @Gavin-walsh What is `songClicked`? Is it a string?

Comment: songClicked, setSongClicked is a state variable that I set to use throughout the app using the context provider. This is so my music player component can be used from anywhere within the app. I have a grid of song images set up so when it is clicked, that information is stored in songClicked and then used in the music player.

Comment: @Gavin-walsh Yeah but what type of variable is songClicked?

Comment: It takes in the specific songFile (mp3) and the index of that song within the array of songs. songFiles[index]

Comment: So you could say a string and a number?

Comment: @Gavin-walsh Maybe just checking if the current song equal to that stored in state is enough? I updated my answer, check the useEffect.

Comment: Hey! That definitely fixed the infinite loop which is great. Now the pause function doesn't work. Would this have anything to do with the changes? Apologies for the questions, this is all gone above my understanding of these hooks as I'm still new to React!

Comment: Ok, I got it working. Had some more missing things from dependency array. Thanks for all of your help. You saved me hours of time!